# Why does Apache return a 503 error for ant's get task, but not for my browser?

Tags: apache, http, ant

I'm trying to get a file with ant, using the get property. I'm running apache 2, and I can get the file from the indicated URL using wget and firefox, but ant gives me the following error:

```
[get] Error opening connection java.io.IOException:
 Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://localhost/jars/jai_core.jar
```

This is what I'm doing in my build.xml:

```
<get src="http://localhost/jars/jai_core.jar"
     dest="${build.dir}/lib/jai_core.jar"
     usetimestamp="true"/>
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?

**EDIT:** On to something. When I provide the full host name of my box instead of localhost, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

503 is *Service Unavailable*, which probably means that the `src` URL isn't getting interpreted properly and sent by the ANT task or perhaps the JRE.

Here are some things to try:

- As always, with ANT, execute the smallest possible build.xml with **-verbose** to see if that gives any more information, **-debug** for even more information.
- Try the `verbose="true"` attribute on the task.
- use "http://127.0.0.1/jars/jai_core.jar" - depending on what version of the java runtime ANT is executing under, 'localhost' may not be getting resolved correctly.
- Drop the `usetimestamp` attribute just to see if it changes behavior.
- Use another Java based application to try to perform the GET and compare results.

Comment: You can also use the -debug flag when invoking Ant to get some more information if -verbose isn't helpful enough.

Comment: It was a name resolution problem. The canonical host name was not set correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The HTTP request might be going through a proxy which is rejecting the request. Alternatively `ant` might not be using a proxy where it should.

Comment: hi, For my case its very high likely that this is a proxy issue on server. Do you have a recommendation to overcome this? this is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46827235/ant-script-waitfor-does-not-work-on-server